# get last month data in sqlalchemy and flask

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

In Python flask, I wanted to display data between a time period (for example, the last month)
The database type is sqlalchemy

routes:

```
@app.route('/')
@register_breadcrumb(app, '.', 'Home')
def home():
    buys = Buy.query.all()
    return render_template('home.html', buys=buys, title='home page')
```

Model:

```
class Buy(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(120), nullable=False)
    date = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.datetime.now())
    price = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'{self.__class__.__name__}({self.id}, {self.title[:30]}, {self.date})'
```

Comment: Can you add the model class and what you've tried so far?

Comment: Yeah. edited my questions

Comment: Try method filter to the query. sqlalchemy ORM documentation is your friend. Search for sqlalchemy orm querying.

Answer (score -1):

You can make use of sqlalchemy ORM filter method as mentioned by @petr-blahos to achieve your goal.

For e.g. you have current month (September) and August data in Buy table like:

[image]

```
today = datetime.date.today()
first = today.replace(day=1)

last_month_last_day = first - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
last_month_first_day = last_month_last_day.replace(day=1)

buys = Buy.objects.filter(date__gte=datetime.date(year=last_month_first_day.year, month=last_month_first_day.month, day=last_month_first_day.day),
                          date__lte=datetime.date(year=last_month_last_day.year, month=last_month_last_day.month, day=last_month_last_day.day))
```

After applying above object filter, you will get desired result.

Please note that, this is done based on only date and not time.

[image]